# QWidget::setLayout error : Attempting to set QLayout [...], which already has a layout

Tags: qt, qt4, qlayout

On execution (no compile error) I get on the console

> QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on CGSearchResult "",
>   which already has a layout

I am using the following code:

```
CGSearchResult::CGSearchResult(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

    initControls();
    SetTableContent();

}

void CGSearchResult::initControls()
{


   backButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Back"));
   connect(backButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showHome()));

   model=new QStandardItemModel();


         QWidget::setFont(QFont("Courier New", 8, QFont::Bold));

        searchTable = new QTableView(this);
        searchTable->showGrid();

        searchTable->resize(720,400);
        searchTable->horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(170);
        searchTable->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(50);
        searchTable->verticalHeader()->hide();
        searchTable->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
        searchTable->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);


    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
    layout->addWidget(backButton, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    layout->addWidget(searchTable, 2, 0, 1, 1);

    setLayout(layout);


}
```

Comment: please fix your code formatting (by indenting it all with 4 spaces - to do that, select your code and press ctrl-K)

Comment: Post unmodified source - the snippet you present is obviously incomplete (for example there is no SetTableContent implementation, the model is not set on searchTable). Only then someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Actully Chalup, I have implemented the setModel method on the SetTableContent method..one more thing this widget is calling from the another class.(QMainWindow).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setLayout

> If there already is a layout manager installed on this widget, QWidget won't let you install another. You must first delete the existing layout manager (returned by layout()) before you can call setLayout() with the new layout.

Comment: How to  find the layout manger already installed or not? Could you please tell me?

Comment: Thanks Ronny... I got it.. I used qDeleteAll(myQWidget->children());

Comment: I think testing whether layout() != 0 suffices